# How do you execute rustc when it is installed in another users's home directory?

Tags: rust

I downloaded and installed the Rust compiler via:

```
sudo curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

Although prefixed with sudo, it still installs to a local directory: `$HOME/.cargo`

From the account where it is installed, doing `rustc --version` gives `1.16.0  (...)`.

**I would like to execute rustc from a Linux account different than the one in which it was installed. Is this possible?**

I created a logical link to the `.cargo` directory and added `$HOME/.cargo/bin` to the front of my PATH.

But, `rustc --version` from this other account gives this puzzling message:

```
error: no default toolchain configured
```

Comment: Instead of investing time into a crude workaround you should install the toolchain in a clean way. Use your systems software management system instead of attempting a wild install that relies on some bundled script.

Comment: @arkascha Using `rustup` is the [officially recommended method](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/install.html).

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Recommended by whom? See? ;-) Many solutions exist where a recommendation exists to use some script bundled with the product, give it full administrative rights and execute it blindly. Does that mean that is a good idea? No!

Comment: @arkascha Recommended by the official Rust-team as I linked the official website... about the `curl | bash` thing: it's quite a controversial topic, but only because it already looks dangerous. There are many explanations ([one example](https://sandstorm.io/news/2015-09-24-is-curl-bash-insecure-pgp-verified-install)) out there why it's not as bad as it sounds and why most other methods are worse than everyone thinks (for example, most installation methods (take `.deb` files) allow arbitrary code execution as root anyway). But I think this is not the right place to discuss this.

Comment: @I did not want to discuss this. You started ;-) Security is not gained by the package format, but by the repositories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you install via `rustup` (which is recommended) you have **two** important folders in your home directory: `.cargo` and `.rustup` (and depending on your version a soft link `.multirust` pointing to `.rustup` for backwards-compatibility reasons). So you also have to create a link to `.rustup`. That's what the strange error message is all about.

> I would like to execute rustc from a Linux account different than the one in which it was installed. Is this possible?

This, however, is a different question. It's important to note that many commands, even just `cargo build`, will attempt to write in one of those directories (in case of `cargo build` to cache downloaded crates). If the second user has full read/write/execute permissions inside both directories mentioned above, it should work -- but it's quite questionable if that's a good solution. If you want, you can move both folders anywhere you like, give both users full permissions to both and create soft-links per user.

---

But again, depending on how much privacy is needed, it gets more complicated (but if, say, you have an account for your work and one account for your hobby stuff, this isn't that important). Here is an overview over both folders:

- `~/.cargo/<several files>`: small, user specific, somewhat confidential files (may contain login data for crates.io)
- `~/.cargo/bin`: installed programs and proxies for programs (around 100MB), execute permission needed
- `~/.cargo/registry`: library cache, can get quite big, not confidential
- `~/.rustup/toolchains`: installed compiler versions and everything else you can install via `rustup`
- `~/.rustup/<tmp and update-hashes>`: somewhat temporary files
- `~/.rustup/settings.toml`: small, user specific

So depending in your needs you can have *real* `.cargo` and `.rustup` folders in your home directory and just soft link the folders like `.cargo/bin` and so on.

Comment: Is the purpose of programming to produce executable to be executed by people other than the programmer?  This is my first day trying to figure out whether to use Rust or not.  The common usage seems limited to the usage by the programmer. Or you do cargo publish to push to some shared the location where it is shared by everyone.  Seems the other users on the same computer have to invade the programmer's home to use the executable.